# Output values from Textbox using Constructor - Prototype

Tags: javascript

i am trying to output the inserted values in the textboxes when the button(John) is click. At the moment i have just added default values
in here ( John= new Player(30,"England",3)); but i would like these value to be picked from the textboxes. Please advise how would i go about doing it.
I tried getting the values from textboxes and assigning to variables (x,y,z  commented out in script)and passing here ( John= new Player(x,y,z));
but it didn't seem to work.

```
Age : <input type = "text" id = "test1" /><br>
County : <input type = "text" id = "test2" /><br>
Rank: <input type = "text" id = "test3" /><br>

<button type="button" onclick="John.myPlayer()">John</button>

<br>

<br>
<div id = "box"></div>
<br>



<script type="text/javascript">

// var x = document.getElementById('test1').value;
// var y = document.getElementById('test2').value;
// var z = document.getElementById('test3').value);

function Player(a,c,r){
this.age=a;
this.country=c;
this.rank=r;
}

Player.prototype.myPlayer = function(){

document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = "John is from " + this.country + " he is       " + this.age + " years old and his rank is " + this.rank;

}

John= new Player(30,"England",3);

John.myPlayer()


</script>
```

Comment: Move the code with `var x, y, z` into the `myPlayer` function to fetch the entered values when you click the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to create a function that is called on the onclick event, and read the values from the textboxes there, after which you create a new instance of Player.

```
<button type="button" onclick="createNewPlayer()">John</button>
```

and in javascript:

```
function createNewPlayer() {

  var x = document.getElementById('test1').value;
  var y = document.getElementById('test2').value;
  var z = document.getElementById('test3').value);

  John= new Player(x, y, z);
  John.myPlayer()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function show(){

        var age = document.getElementById('test1').value;
        var country = document.getElementById('test2').value;
        var rank = document.getElementById('test3').value;

        John = new Player(age, country, rank);
        John.myPlayer();
    }
    Player.prototype.myPlayer = function() {
        var output = "John is from " + this.country + " he is " + this.age + " years old and his rank is " + this.rank;
        document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = output;
}

    function Player(a,c,r){
        this.age=a;
        this.country=c;
        this.rank=r;
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>

    Age : <input type = "text" id = "test1" /><br>
    County : <input type = "text" id = "test2" /><br>
    Rank: <input type = "text" id = "test3" /><br>

    <div id="box">
    </div>

    <button type="button" onclick="show()">John</button>

</body>
</html>
```